# Is there a way to create a ReplSet using mongo-topology-manager

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have gone through documentation [mongo_topology](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-topology-manager) to create a simple ReplSet. To be honest, i just replicated the same example however i am stuck with the below issue.

```
2019-11-26T15:46:33.051Z mongoose version: 5.7.12
D:\Alexa\node_modules\mongodb-topology-manager\lib\replset.js:124
        .toString()
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Alexa\node_modules\mongodb-topology-manager\lib\replset.js:124:14)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:658:12)
```

I have gone through various forums but none was able to give answer that fixes the issue. Is there any way to debug the below issue ?.

Below is the code

```
const { ReplSet } = require('mongodb-topology-manager');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

run().catch(error => console.error(error));

async function run() {

   await setupReplicaSet();

   const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:31000,localhost:31001,localhost:31002/' +'test?replicaSet=rs0';

   await mongoose.connect(uri);
   await mongoose.connection.createCollection('Person');


   const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: String
   });
   const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema, 'Person');

   Person.watch().
     on('change', data => console.log(new Date(), data));

   console.log(new Date(), 'Inserting doc');
   await Person.create({ name: 'Axl Rose' });
   console.log(new Date(), 'Inserted doc');
 }

async function setupReplicaSet() {
   const bind_ip = 'localhost';
   const replSet = new ReplSet('mongod', [
   { options: { port: 31000, dbpath: 
   `${__dirname}/data/db/31000`, bind_ip } },
   { options: { port: 31001, dbpath: 
   `${__dirname}/data/db/31001`, bind_ip } },
   { options: { port: 31002, dbpath: 
   `${__dirname}/data/db/31002`, bind_ip } }
   ], { replSet: 'rs0' });

  // Initialize the replica set
  await replSet.purge();
  await replSet.start();
  console.log(new Date(), 'Replica set started...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I eventually just realized that mongod was not in the path. Adding that fixed it.